# FCM onMessage not working in Firefox, but working in chrome

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firefox, firebase-cloud-messaging

my code is **working perfectly** on chrome (Version 103.0.5060.134), but when i tried it on firefox (103.0) **it's not working**.

the service worker registered successfully, but cannot receive notification/message.
there's no error shown up in console

here my code (i'm using vue v2 btw)

*firebase-messaging-sw.js*

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-app-compat.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.2.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js')

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
// your app's Firebase config object.
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'api-key',
  authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://project-id.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'project-id',
  storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'sender-id',
  appId: 'app-id',
  measurementId: 'G-measurement-id',
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

*registerServiceWorker.js*

```
import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready () {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.' 
        
      )
    },
    registered () {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
    },
    cached () {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updatefound () {
      console.log('New content is downloading.')
    },
    updated () {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
    },
    offline () {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error (error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. FCM notifications have stopped working completely on Firefox. I contacted Firebase Support but they are reporting that there is no known outage going on right now and asked me to provide reproducible code. Conversation is still ongoing.

Comment: Firebase Support has reproduced the issue and they are looking into it.

Comment: I have seen the same thing. Have you heard anything new?

Comment: @skynew do you find any resolution ?

Comment: @hu7sy They asked to regenerate webpush certificates. I have tested doing it but still issue is happening. They have acknowledged my response and and are still looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has acknowledged this as an issue and it is now showing up on Firebase Status page. https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/MnhJwvhMnsvoAsACiSi2