# Firebase FCM HTTP legacy suddenly stop working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

By some unknown reasons, within 3 weeks ago, I suddenly cannot send notification to Google Firebase FCM. Before that, it worked well and all clients can receive notifications normally after I push something to FCM.

I did that by POST a request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Headers are `Content-Type: application/json`, `Authorization: key=AAAAKFe-...oRpS`. The key got from settings liked in this link [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDPEv.png)

Body liked this

```js
{
    "to": "dmx5JJ...dnPb7",
    "data": {
        "title": "title",
        "alertId": 1276318267,
        "alertMappingId": 1238716233,
        "data": "hehehe"
    }
}
```

with "to" is `idToken` retrieve from web client.

Google returned success HTTP response, but its content is AuthenticationError:

`{"multicast_id":5347538896185294090,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"AuthenticationError"}]}`

Did I made any mistakes? Or Google Firebase just changed some policies? Someone please help me with this :'(

PS: I tried switch to HTTP v1, but still got similar result :'(

```js
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
        "details": [{
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
            "errorCode": "THIRD_PARTY_AUTH_ERROR"
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this's maybe a bug happened in Firefox only. Above code still works well in Chrome or Edge.

There're an issue liked this too:
[FCM onMessage not working in Firefox, but working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73164322/fcm-onmessage-not-working-in-firefox-but-working-in-chrome)